# What is a good alarm clock app for OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

I am looking for an alarm clock on OS X that is reliable and works with itunes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Alarm Clock: http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/ipod_itunes/alarmclock.html

Comment: Probably will do the job, will see if there are any other options.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [Awaken](http://embraceware.com/awaken/), $15, before getting an iPhone to do the job. You can get it to use playlists in iTunes, it works really well.